# getID3 is not working in my local xampp

Tags: php, xampp, getid3

I'm trying to get the video duration in my local XAMPP setup. I have just downloaded the getID3 zip and added it as :

```
include_once($base_url . '/getid3/getid3/getid3.php');
$getID3 = new getID3;
$file = $getID3->analyze($filepath);
```

But it renders the following error:

```
Fatal error</b>:  Class 'getID3' not found
```

Do I need to enable any library on the PHP side?

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Also please do check if the class file exists there....

```
<?php

include_once(dirname(__FILE) . '/getid3/getid3/getid3.php');
$getID3 = new getID3;
$file = $getID3->analyze($filepath);

?>
```